Wouldn't this corollary imply that weak convergence implies strong convergence? (Kreyszig 4.3-4)
I'm studying "Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications" book by Kreyszig.
Corollary 4.3-4 states the following:

For every $x$ in a normed space $X$ we have:
$$ \lVert x \rVert = \sup_{f \in X', f \neq 0} \dfrac{|f(x)|}{\lVert f \Vert}$$
Hence if $x_0$ is such that $f(x_0)=0$ for all $f \in X'$ then $x_0=0$

Here $X'$ denotes the dual space of $X$.
Is this corollary right? Wouldn't this imply that weak convergence implies strong convergence? Because if $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ then $|f(x_n)-f(x)| \to 0$ for all $f \in X'$ and by the previous corollary we would have:
$$ \lVert x_n - x \rVert = \sup_{f \in X', f \neq 0} \dfrac{|f(x_n-x)|}{\lVert f \Vert} = \sup_{f \in X', f \neq 0} \dfrac{|f(x_n)-f(x)|}{\lVert f \Vert}\xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0$$
So $x_n \to x$.
But I know that It is not true in general that if $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ (while $" \rightharpoonup "$ denotes weak convergence) then $x_n \to x$, so I would be grateful if you could tell me if I am misinterpreting the corollary or if it is wrong.

If $x_n \to x$ weakly, then
then for all $f \in X'$ with $f \ne 0$, we have,
$$
\dfrac{|f(x_n)-f(x)|}{\lVert f \Vert}\xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0 .
$$
But that does not imply
$$
\sup_{f \in X', f \neq 0} \dfrac{|f(x_n)-f(x)|}{\lVert f \Vert}\xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0
$$
Putting the "$\sup$" on there makes it strong convergence.

Consider, for example $f_n$ an orthonormal sequence in Hilbert space, so $f_n  \to 0$ weakly, but not strongly.

Ok thanks... I was thinking that the implication was true for the $\sup$ because it was true for each $f \in X'$, but that might have been the mistake..

@MC2 Think of the difference of pointwise and uniform convergence of functions: Pointwise convergence means $|g_n(x)-g(x)|\to0$ for every $x$, while uniform convergence means $\sup_{x}|g_n(x)-g(x)|\to0$. Pointwise convergence does not imply uniform convergence
